# Dealing with NULL values in JSON

Tags: jquery, json, null

I have a stream of JSON coming back and am building a table dynamically with it's values. I'm having an issue where values which are "NULL" in the database are actually being returned in the JSON with a NULL value.

I'd rather my output to my users not display NULL.

Is there a more efficient way of handling this other than how I am doing it?

```
if(data[i][2] != null){ 
foo = '';
 }else{
foo = data[i][2];
}               
htmlString += '<td>' + foo+ '</td>';
```

Comment: Is the value a string containing `"NULL"` or js `null`?

Comment: data[i][2] is a reference to the 2nd element of the current row (loop) within a JSON stream.

Comment: Yeah, but I mean, what is the actually representation of the value? Is it a value that will evaluate to false? Can you post a sample of the actual JSON?

Comment: Ah I see, it actually says null in the stream e.g ["113","test",null,"",""],

Comment: Didn't you interchange the instructions ? You are storing an empty string if the value is different to null. Is that normal ?

Comment: Please see if the value of data[i][2] is really a null object or a string "NULL". If it is a string your statement will not be evaluated.

Comment: Another question : you cannot do this on the service layer in the function returning the json stream ?

Comment: One way is to simply set null values to an empty string in the SQL query. For example in MySQL: Select ifnull(mycolumn, ""), ... where ...

Comment: Well, if i do select ISNULL(column,'') from table in my service layer it returns a 0 (since it is a numeric), and then my JSON has a 0 in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cleanData = data[i][2] || '';
```

this is equivalent for

```
if(data[i][2] == null){ 
    cleanData = '';
    }
else{
    cleanData = data[i][2];
    }
```

take value of data[i][2] when it has some, else take the second one

```
cleanData = data[i][2] || 'my fall back value';
```

The value of data[i][2] will be assigned to cleanData if its not evalated to false, for Eg :false, null, undefined, 0, zero-length string or NaN are evaluated to false. Otherwise 'my fall back value' is taken.
So obviously, if your variable need to take up any of these values(like 0) the solution is not perfect.

```
cleanData = (data[i][2] == null)? '' : data[i][2];
```

looks more reliable.

Comment: could you add a bit of explanation? It'd make it way easier for other people to understand your answer :)